# upload MapKit region to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit

I try to save a map with the users location to a post, but I get **Value of type 'MKMapView?' has no member 'MKMapView'** as an error all the time...
The following shows my code but I leave out any background code to the images and labels as everything there works fine, I just include them in here so you know how I save the post informations... Do you know what my error is and how I can solve it?

```
var takenMap: MKMapView!

@IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if textView.text != "" && takenImage != nil && userLocation.text != "" {
        // Create and save a new job
        let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: takenImage!, addedByUser: (userLabel?.text)!, userImage: UserImage, location: userLocation.text, map: takenMap.MKMapView)
        newJob.save()
}

//MARK:- CLLocationManager Delegates
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map = takenMap

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(lastLocation) { (placeMarks, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let firstLocation = placeMarks?[0] {
                    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

                    if let cityName = firstLocation.locality,
                        let street = firstLocation.thoroughfare {

                        self.scanLocation = "\(street), \(cityName)"
                        print("This is the current city name", cityName)
                        print("this is the current street address", street)
                        self.takenLocation = self.scanLocation!
                        self.userLocation.text = self.takenLocation
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Job.swift:

```
var map: String?

init(map: String? = nil) {
    self.map = map
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        map = value["location"] as? String
    }
}

func save() {
    let newPostKey = ref.key

    // save jobImage
    if let imageData = jobImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("jobImages/\(newPostKey)")

        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
            self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let postDictionary = [
                "map" : self.map!
                ] as [String : Any]
            self.ref.setValue(postDictionary)
        })
    }
}
```

I left out any code for labels or whatever out so the snippet won't be too long

Answer (score 0):

The code `takenMap.MKMapView` should probably just be `takenMap`.

Comment: tried it, but then it says **Cannot convert value of type 'MKMapView?' to expected argument type 'String?'**

Comment: Why does `Job` expect the type `String` for a property named `map`? Maybe include that code too.

Comment: could you maybe check my edited question? I've added the code for the job.swift file